# SOSL search result in c# for salesforce integration

Tags: sosl

I have used the SOSL to get the salesforce record.

SOSL  search result in c# for salesforce integration?

Comment: There is a C# sample in this [search documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_search.htm) that is very close to what you are trying to accomplish in terms of accessing the Salesforce data.

Comment: Yes I have gone through that but I dont know how to load the data grid. Please help.

Comment: You may get more help on that from another site; e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+data+grid returns 11k results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: get the search result.
Step 2: get the field names and store to list
Step 3: parse the search result again by using the xml and find the fields based on the field name

> Refer:
>   www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_search.htm